# How to map a query result to case class using Anorm in scala

Tags: scala, anorm

I have 2 case classes like this :

```
case class ClassTeacherWrapper(
                          success: Boolean,
                          classes: List[ClassTeacher]
                        )
```

2nd one :

```
case class ClassTeacher(
                      clid: String,
                      name: String
                    )
```

And a query like this :

```
  val query =
    SQL"""
      SELECT
        s.section_sk::text AS clid,
         s.name AS name
         from
       ********************
    """
```

P.S. I put * in place of query for security reasons :

So my query is returning 2 values. How do i map it to `case class ClassTeacher`

currently I am doing something like this :

```
def getClassTeachersByInstructor(instructor: String, section: String): ClassTeacherWrapper = {

implicit var conn: Connection = null
try {

  conn = datamartDatasourceConnectionPool.getDBConnection()
  // Define query
  val query =
    SQL"""
      SELECT
        s.section_sk::text AS clid,
         s.name AS name
       ********
    """



  logger.info("Read from DB: " + query)


  // create a List containing all the datasets from the resultset and return
  new ClassTeacherWrapper(
       success =true,
      query.as(Macro.namedParser[ClassTeacher].*)

  )
  //Trying new approch
  //val users = query.map(user => new ClassTeacherWrapper(true, user[Int]("clid"), user[String]("name")).tolist
}
catch {
  case NonFatal(e) =>
    logger.error("getGradebookScores: error getting/parsing data from DB", e)
    throw e
  }
}
```

with is I am getting this exception :

```
{
   "error": "ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = character varying\n  
    Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You 
    might need to add explicit type casts.\n  Position: 324"
 }
```

Can anyone help where am I going wrong. I am new to scala and Anorm 
What should I modify in `query.as`  part of code

Comment: The error `ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = character varying` is raised from the DB, when it parses the query, as it try to compare incompatibles types `uuid` with `varchar` (`string`). I guess `********` in the query includes the `WHERE` clause causing that, but without it, it cannot be confirmed/helped.

Comment: BTW the code include some "warts" as `!!var!! connection` (resource mutability), `query.as(Macro.namedParser[ClassTeacher].*)` (`RowParser` materialized for each query)

Answer (score 2):

Do you need the success field? Often an empty list would suffice?

I find parsers very useful (and reusable), so something like the following in the ClassTeacher singleton (or similar location):

```
val fields = "s.section_sk::text AS clid, s.name"

val classTeacherP =
  get[Int]("clid") ~
  get[String]("name") map {
    case clid ~ name =>
    ClassTeacher(clid,name)
  }

def allForInstructorSection(instructor: String, section: String):List[ClassTeacher] = 
  DB.withConnection { implicit c => //-- or injected db
    SQL(s"""select $fields from ******""")
      .on('instructor -> instructor, 'section -> section)
      .as(classTeacherP *)
  }
```

Comment: It would be nice to be able to generate a parser based on a case class. Do you know if there is a way to do it in the most recent versions?

Comment: I think the way to go @costa, would be macros. They have changed in the most recent versions - you don't say which version you are using. Let us know if you come right, it would definitely be useful!

Comment: I used scala 2.13.6. I tried to use scala 3 but I got errors in sbt  - anorm didn't resolve.

Comment: I don't think Play is ready for Scala 3 yet, but Scala 2 [has macros](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html).

Comment: I usually stayed away from macros, however, magnolia makes them palatable: https://github.com/softwaremill/magnolia/tree/scala2. I am going to look into it to see if it is possible to derive a parser from a case class.

Comment: @costa Magnolia looks great, thank you for that!

Comment: It turns out anorm implemented macros: see here: https://github.com/playframework/anorm/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/anorm/Macro.scala. Here is a sample: `implicit val cn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://<server>:1433/<db>");
  case class Table(tableName: String)
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    val parser = Macro.namedParser[Table]
    val sqlQuery = SQL(
      """ select v.table_catalog + '.' + v.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + v.TABLE_NAME as tableName from information_schema.views v order by 1;""").as(parser *)
    println(sqlQuery.mkString("\n"))
  }`